# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-a)^{k-1}a = \frac{1}{a}$ for $0 \lt a \lt 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-a)^{k-1}a = \frac{1}{a}$ for $0 \lt a \lt 1$

This is the expected value of dice rolls before rolling a 1 with a dice with $\frac{1}{a}$ sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No calculus needed:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-a)^{k-1}a &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^k (1-a)^{k-1}a
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=j}^\infty (1-a)^{k-1}a
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(1-a)^{j-1}}{1-(1-a)}a
\\&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty (1-a)^{j-1}
\\&=\frac1{1-(1-a))}
\\&=\frac1{a}.
\end{align}

The rearrangements are justified by the absolute convergence of the geometric series in question since $0\lt a \lt 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: divide by $a$ and integrate.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $1+x+x^2+\cdots+ x^k+\cdots  = \dfrac{1}{1-x}, |x| < 1$. Differentiate both sides and plug $x = 1-a$ into the equation to get the answer.